# npm update: local history of package changes?

Tags: node.js, npm

We run `npm update` from time to time, with a few packages at an approximated version, such as `~1.0.0`. This generally works.

However, recently, we started to experience application problems that we cannot trace to our own code, and we suspect that running `npm update` updated some package to some new version, but we can't be sure.

So, my question: **Is there a file (or similar) that shows the history `npm update` operations - i.e. which packages were changed on the local machine, and to what they were changed, and when the change took place, etc.**

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the [`npm shrinkwrap` command](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap). If you version control the resulting `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file, it will provide you with a history of the different versions. Just be sure you understand how shrinkwrap locks down dependencies.

Comment: that's a good point. we've looked at shrinkwrap (for this sort of purpose) in the past, but never pulled the trigger. perhaps this is the time.. :)   leaving the question unanswered for now in case there is a direct answer somewhere out there.